# Layered Architecture TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, oop

Tomorow i have an exam and must use Layered Architecture.So I want to make an StartApp module which will make the inheritance between my classes. It looks like this:

```
from Domain.Domain import *
from Repository.Repository import *
from Controller.Controller import *
from UI.UI import *

repo = Repository("rezervari.txt")
contro = Controller(repo)
ui = UI(contro)

ui.main_menu()
```

But i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/catalin/PycharmProjects/untitled1/StartApp.py", line 7, in <module>
    contro = Controller(repo)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

And i really can't figure out how to fix this error.
My Repository module looks like this:

```
from Domain.Domain import *

class RepositoryException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message):
        self._message = message

    def getMessage(self):
        return self.getMessage()

    def __str__(self):
        return self._message

class Repository:

    def __init__(self, fileName):
        self._repo = []
        self._fileName = fileName
        self.ReadFile(self.getFileName())

    def getFileName(self):
        return self._fileName

    def getAll(self):
        return self._repo

    def ReadFile(self, fileName):
        f = open(fileName, 'r')
        line = f.readline().strip()
        l = line.split()
        end = True
        if l != [] :
            end = False
        while not end :
            r = Reservation(l[0], l[1], l[2], l[3])
            self.getAll().append(r)
            line = f.readline().strip()
            l = line.split()
            if l == "":
                end = True
        f.close()

    def AddRes(self, fileName, name, arrival, departure, room):
        r = Reservation(name, arrival, departure, room)
        self.getAll().append(r)
        self.WriteFile(self, self.getFileName())

    def WriteFile(self, fileName):
        f = open(fileName, 'w')
        for i in self.getAll():
            f.write(str(i) + "\n")
        f.close()
```

Comment: First, import with from xxx import * is a terrible idea.  If several modules have the same classnames your code won't work.  Drop into a python shell and import Controller.  Then do help on it to see what is in it.  Continue down until you find what you need.  It looks like Controller.Controller.Controller is not a module

Comment: Multiple star imports is really bad practice.